# pysnmp: Values not same as SNMPWalk -- WHY?

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

In short,

I am utilizing pysnmp to get multiple values to create a .CSV containing routing table information.

When I do an SNMPWALK I on OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3 I get:

```
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.0 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.254
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.2 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.254
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.14 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.254
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.18 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.254
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.22 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.254
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.26 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.254
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.30 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.254
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.32 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.254
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.65 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.248
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.97 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.248
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.10.30.0.128 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.255
IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.127.0.0.50 = IpAddress: 255.0.0.0
```

While utilizing the same method in my pysnmp script, I get the following output:

```
-> snmpNetMAsk = (snmpDictClean(snmpNetMAsk, 10))
(Pdb) pprint.pprint(snmpNetMAsk)
[[(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.0)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffffe'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.2)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffffe'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.14)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffffe'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.18)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffffe'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.22)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffffe'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.26)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffffe'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.30)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffffe'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.32)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffffe'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.65)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffff8'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.97)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='fffffff8'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.10.30.0.128)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='ffffffff'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.127.0.0.50)),
   IpAddress(hexValue='ff000000'))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.0)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.2)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.14)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.18)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.22)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.26)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.30)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.32)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.65)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.97)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.10.30.0.128)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.4.127.0.0.50)), Integer(1))],
 [(MibVariable(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.5.10.30.0.0)), Integer(18024))]]
```

As you can clearly see, all  of  my values are in HEX, and then copied to some Interger. I do not fully understand what is going on here. It seems easier to just run an snmpwalk in the terminal and capture it to a file, then edit the file with a python script. If there is a way to maintain the values in a dictionary using pysnnmp, I would much rather do that. I only ask this after days of searching on my own. Thanks for any help!

**EDIT: Showing a full version of the script I am using.**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pprint
import pysnmp
from snmp_helper import *


def snmpDictClean(input_list, input_num):
    output_dict = dict()
    for varBindTableRow in input_list:
        for name, val in varBindTableRow:
            name = str(name)
            val = str(val)
            splitKey = name.split('.')
            del splitKey[0:input_num]
            splitKey = '.'.join(splitKey)
            output_dict[splitKey] = val
    return output_dict


def main():

    ipCidrRouteIfIndex = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.4.24.4.1.5'
    ifDescr = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2'
    ipAdEntIfIndex = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.2'
    ipAdEntNetMask = '.1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3'

    # SNMPv3 Connection Parameters
    a_user = 'USER'
    auth_key = 'AUTH_KEY'
    encrypt_key = 'ENCRYPT_KEY'

    snmp_user = (a_user, auth_key, encrypt_key)

    ipAddr = [
        'host1',
        'host2',
        ]

    for hlist in ipAddr:
        snmpDevice = (hlist, 161)

        snmpRoute = snmp_bulk_oid_v3(snmpDevice, snmp_user, oid=ipCidrRouteIfIndex)
        snmpRoute = (snmpDictClean(snmpRoute, 11))

        snmpIfDescr = snmp_bulk_oid_v3(snmpDevice, snmp_user, oid=ifDescr)
        snmpIfDescr = (snmpDictClean(snmpIfDescr, 10))

        snmpIpIndex = snmp_bulk_oid_v3(snmpDevice, snmp_user, oid=ipAdEntIfIndex)
        snmpIpIndex = (snmpDictClean(snmpIpIndex, 10))

        snmpNetMAsk = snmp_bulk_oid_v3(snmpDevice, snmp_user, oid=ipAdEntNetMask)
        snmpNetMAsk = (snmpDictClean(snmpNetMAsk, 10))

        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

**I am using snmp_helper from @ktbyers: https://github.com/ktbyers/pynet/tree/master/snmp. I modified it to use snmpbulk instead of get.**

```
# Python

from __future__ import print_function
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
import pprint

def snmp_bulk_oid_v3(snmp_device, snmp_user, oid='', auth_proto='sha',
                    encrypt_proto='des', display_errors=True):
    # unpack snmp_user
    a_user, auth_key, encrypt_key = snmp_user

    auth_proto_map = {
        'sha':  cmdgen.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
        'md5':  cmdgen.usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol,
        'none': cmdgen.usmNoAuthProtocol
    }

    if auth_proto in auth_proto_map.keys():
        auth_protocol = auth_proto_map[auth_proto]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid authentication protocol specified: %s" % auth_proto)

    encrypt_proto_map = {
        'des':      cmdgen.usmDESPrivProtocol,
        '3des':     cmdgen.usm3DESEDEPrivProtocol,
        'aes128':   cmdgen.usmAesCfb128Protocol,
        'aes192':   cmdgen.usmAesCfb192Protocol,
        'aes256':   cmdgen.usmAesCfb256Protocol,
        'none':     cmdgen.usmNoPrivProtocol,
    }

    if encrypt_proto in encrypt_proto_map.keys():
        encrypt_protocol = encrypt_proto_map[encrypt_proto]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid encryption protocol specified: %s" % encrypt_proto)

    # Create a PYSNMP cmdgen object
    cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

    (errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable) = cmdGen.bulkCmd(

        cmdgen.UsmUserData(a_user, auth_key, encrypt_key,
            authProtocol=auth_protocol,
            privProtocol=encrypt_protocol, ),
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(snmp_device),
        0,
        25,
        oid,
        lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True 
    )

    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)
    else:
        if errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (
                errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
                )
            )

        '''
        else:
            for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
                for name, val in varBindTableRow:
                    snmp_data = print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
        '''

    return varBindTable
```

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error you are having. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is vanilla OID-value pairs as received from SNMP Agent. To get prettier output with pysnmp you need to get it passing received OID-value pairs through MIB resolver. Use [this](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v2c-with-mib-resolution.html) example as a prototype but additionally load IP-MIB like this:

```
...
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
    MibVariable('1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3').loadMibs('IP-MIB'),
    lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True
)
...
```

Make sure to use .prettyPrint() for printing out OIDs/values.

Keep in mind that you need conventional ASN.1 IP-MIB converted into pysnmp format to make it usable by pysnmp. You could do that with (yet experimental) [pysmi MIB compiler](http://sf.net/projects/pysmi/) or with build-pysnmp-mib script shipped with pysnmp or just install a pre-built MIB collection from PyPI (pip pysnmp-mibs).

If you get your own IP-MIB.py, rather than using pysnmp-mibs package, you could put your IP-MIB.py into a directory and point pysnmp to that custom location through MibVariable.addMibSource() method. See [this example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v1-with-custom-mibs-location.html) for more information. All MibVariable methods could be chained like this:

```
MibVariable('1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3').addMibSource('/etc/pymibs').loadMibs('IP-MIB')
```

or you could skip .loadMibs() by specifying MIB name to load in initialiser:

```
MibVariable('IP-MIB', 'ipRoute').addMibSource('/etc/pymibs')
```

The MibVariable class is polymorphic to ObjectIdentifier, so those two could be used interchangeably. But MibVariable could gather more information related to the OID it was initialised with from a MIB file. For instance MibVariable may contain MIB module name and MIB symbol name associated with the OID in question. It can also hold a SNMP data type of a value associated with that OID.

You can think of MibVariable as an implementation of SNMPv2-SMI's OBJECT-TYPE macro.

Comment: Thank you for the response @IIya Etingof I am going to try to go down this route. It might take me a while as I am a little new to this. I'll keep this updated with my results.

Comment: I was able to convert IP-MIB into a pysnmp readable file. Where would I put the new MIB file? Also, what does MibVariable class represent? Thanks  @Ilya Etingof

Comment: I went ahead and loaded the MIB correctly after downloading and converting it. The default MIB builtin with pysnmp is the same after comparing them. I also specified the initialiser, it works, but I still end up with the same result, so this did not fix my issue. However, I do understand better what is going on. So thank you for explaining it.

Comment: Make sure to use .prettyPrint() for printing out OIDs/values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to look the same, you'll need to use something other than `pprint` to format it. Try this:

```
    for row in snmpNetMAsk:
        for name, val in row:
            print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
```

Reference: http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v2c.html

Comment: Thanks @Robᵩ but prettyprint still prints the hex value without the oid reference.